# how can I tell the mail command the path to sendmail?

Tags: mail-command

I would the `mail` command to use a program other than `/usr/sbin/sendmail`.
e.g.

```
$ mail --path=/usr/local/bin/mysendmail someone@somewhere.com
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What version of `mail` is this?

Comment: @thrig sorry yeah I should have mentioned. BSD-mail package in unbuntu repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bsd-mail (which Debian calls the `bsd-mailx` package) a `sendmail` option can be set in the `~/.mailrc` file:

```
set sendmail=/root/alternatemailer
```

Which could instead be `ssmtp` or something or a simple shell script to test that this even works as documented.

```
$ cat /root/alternatemailer
#!/bin/sh
cat >> /root/meh
$ rm /root/meh
$ echo foo | mail -s blah nobody@example.org
$ file /root/meh
meh: ASCII text
$
```